# how to open listview window explorer in listview control

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a listview window browser thats working completely fine .i open folder through folder browser and the files and folders in that particular directory opens in the listview via using

```
PopulateListView(path)
```

now in my mouse double click event im opening a particular file and folder it opens the file but when it opens the directory a new window pops up .i want that directory to b opened in the listview control...the code for this scenarioa is

```
private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            string pathdoubleClicked = listView1.FocusedItem.Tag.ToString();
          PopulateListView(pathdoubleClicked);

            Process.Start(pathdoubleClicked);
             simpleStack.Push(pathdoubleClicked);
        }
```

now i want to do it with if else like if the path is of drectory then go to populatelistview method other wise process.start but its now working any idea how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, if the path is a directory, you want to display its content on double-click. If it's a file, you want to open it.

So you would simply do:

```
private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    string pathdoubleClicked = listView1.FocusedItem.Tag.ToString();

    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathdoubleClicked))
    {
        PopulateListView(pathdoubleClicked);
    }
    else
    {
        Process.Start(pathdoubleClicked);
    }

    // ?
    simpleStack.Push(pathdoubleClicked);
}
```

Comment: yes exactly.......i did it like if(pathdoubleClicked==directory.getdirectories(folderbrowser.getPath).tostring()) then do that ..and seriously this statement was showing path of dir on debugging:P but now its working my poor coding ahh...thanks anyways